# Image(s) placement over a image in Android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview

I was attempting to place a image on top of another existing image in android.  Here was the game plan.  First the user would select a button and then that button would tell the program to populate a sprite/ image to a fixed location on the master Image.  Once the image is set the user could then hit a button for another image on top of what is currently their, (the goal is two images with a option to change their size, x and y position.  I am only using android 2.1 platform!  The button for selection and the text describing the activity are in a linearlayout.

Comment: try changing the linearlayout for a relativelayout and you will be able to place items above other items, however using relativelayout you will have to specify the position of those.

Comment: so something like this"""   RelativeLayout rL = new .... (this);      r1.setImageRecourse(R.raw.masterPic.png) \rL.addView(r1)  //defaulted to position 0,0 because it was the first element.   Now this is where i think i lose it a little. Image smallpngImage = new ...(this); smallpngImage.setImageRecourse("yata yata");  smallpngImage.setMaxHeight and width but what do i need to do to set the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `RelativeLayout` and then you can use params to set position, margin, etc..
something like this:

```
//this is your fist item
r1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);

//this is the second item
r2.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage2);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams=
new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageParams.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
imageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,r1.getId());
addView(r2,imageParams);
```

Comment: Thanks were getting closer to my desired effect but not their yet.  To change the size is their a way to scale down the image.png by using the r2.setMaxtHeight(10) and width to r2.setMaxWidth(10);  I tried but It look like its the same size of the original 80 pixels/80 pixels/72 resolution. I still don't know how to change the position yet?

Comment: I think you just change the margins around to position the other image to the current one, but i'm stilling having problems sizing my second image down to size.

Comment: margins is the space between elements not the size of the image. To set the size of your image you set it on your LayoutParams.. as you can see in the example it says "LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT" so you can set it to your desired Width and Height.

P.S. Normally images in Android are placed in the drawable folder, and its also recommended that you have an image for the resolutions (drawable-mdpi , drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi... etc) that you wish to support.
here is a good article about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Now lets say the user click the button 10 times of the same picture.  How would one go about making ten new copies and then clearing them out without reopening a new activity or recalling the same activity to force a brand new redraw.  I'm programming right now but I want to make only up to 8 image objects of each type or 'bug' 'cat' 'dog' 'dragonfly' and 'zelda', (100% random names) but I don't want to populate 8 x 5 images and hide them all and then re-show them when I need because it looks messy having that many private statements above the top but still can access them.

Comment: I suggest that you ask this as a new question but remember that the more images you add your app will be consuming resouces and if you dont manage well the memory you could end up crashing your application due to OutOfMemory